# Python -> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, integer, typeerror

I have a list/array **str4** in python, I want to access it with a variable which I strongly believe is an int because I test it with the function **isdigit()** and I also made a manual debug and checked that all the option come out correctly with the only number.

```
temp = "variableX"
file2 = open('file.txt','r')
for line in file2:
  if line.find(temp) =! -1:
    posArray = line.split(temp)[1][1:3]
    if ")" in posArray:
      posArray = posArray[:-1]
    if posArray.isdigit():
      num = posArray
      print temp+"("+num+")"
      print num
      print str4[num]
```

The above code is used to debug, my problem is in the **str4[num]**, the result of the above code is:

```
variableX(1)
1
"this is position 1"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "orderList.py", line34, in <module>
    print str4[num]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Why **num** is a digit but python tells me it is a string?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have just opened the file, you have never read it

Comment: `'2'` and `2` are not the same thing. They are both digits but the first one is a `string` and the second an `integer`. `line` is by default a `string` since it is read from a file. `num` ultimately becomes a part of `line` so it too is `string`.

Comment: use int(num) to convert num to an integer do it before line 34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretor is never wrong...

More seriously, you get num as a substring so it is a string. You must convert it into in int if you want to use it as a string index:

```
  num = int(posArray)          # ok num is now an int
  print temp+"("+str(num)+")"  # must use str to concat it with strings
  print num, type(num), posArray, type(posArray) # num is int, posArray is string
  print str4[num]              # now fine
```

Answer (score 3):

You checked if string posArray is a digit:

```
  if posArray.isdigit():
      num = posArray
```

But you did't convert it to digit, like so:

```
  if posArray.isdigit():
      num = int(posArray)
```

Comment: exactly what i said :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look your code with my comments below. Read it from the bottom to the top to get an idea on how you can easily debug your own code; what the thinking process is.

```
temp = "variableX"
file2 = open('file.txt','r')  # which is a file, so `line` is `string` - CASE CLOSED
for line in file2:  # and `line` is a result of looping through `file2`
  if line.find(temp) =! -1:
    posArray = line.split(temp)[1][1:3]  # and `posArray` is a part of `line`
    if ")" in posArray:
      posArray = posArray[:-1]  # ok, `posArray` is a part of `posArray`
    if posArray.isdigit():  # `posArray` contains digits only but that doesn't help really, so does "123"..
      num = posArray  # ok, so `num` is whatever `posArray` is
      print temp+"("+num+")"
      print num
      print str4[num]  # here is the Error so we start here and work backwards
```

What we show above is that ultimately, `num` will be of the same type as `line` (`str`) and as a result, cannot be used to `index` anything. It must be converted to `int` first by doing `int(num)`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is after

```
num = posArray
```

do:

`print str4[int(num)])`